# how can i link a button in HTML to a node.js file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I am a newbie in Node.js and want to know how can I link the button that
I created to a Node.js file such that when the button is clicked , the node.js file is opened.

app.js

```
var http=require('http');
var fs=require('fs');

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    console.log('request was made: ' +req.url);
    res.writHead(200,{'content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var myReadStream=fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'index.html', 'utf8');
    res.sendDate('hey')
    myReadStream.pipe(res);

});

applicationCache.listen(3002);
server.listen(3002);
console.log('connected');
```

I would love to have any help and support provided.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't 'link' it in the same sense as a PHP file, for example. Node.js needs to run your script and then starts a server listening on the port you specified (3002). To link to that page, you would need to go to `http://localhost:3002`. That will give you the content in the `index.html` file.

Comment: can you please explain how to code that part. I Appreciate the support!